# LINQ aggregate chaining

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

If I have following records

```
ID| YEAR | MONTH
----------------
1 | 1990 | 8
2 | 2011 | 3
3 | 2015 | 1
```

If I want to get latest date, how to achieve this result?

I was thinking of something like this but obviously chaining `Max` syntax won't work

```
list.Max(m => m.Year).Max(m => m.Month)
```

Comment: Possible solution `list.Max(m => new DateTime(m.Year, m.Month, 1));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Max again the way you have tried because [Max](http://list.Max(m%20=%3E%20m.Year).Max(m%20=%3E%20m.Month)) returns the maximum value in that list and not an IEnumerable.

Try this:-

```
list.OrderByDescending(m => m.Year)
    .ThenByDescending(m => m.Month).FirstOrDefault();
```